# My whole div went disappear when I load my div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I want to load just my div not the whole page.  Here Is my code.

My whole HTML div disappears when I load my div using jquery.

I'm using `$(".boxtopm").load(location.href + " .boxtopm");` to reload my div.

```
function edit_revenue(val) {
  var id = val;
  var amount = $('#revenue_amount_' + id).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '{{route('edit_revenue')}}',
    data: {
      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      'id': id,
      'amount': amount
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(".boxtopm").load(location.href + " .boxtopm");
      $('.revnue_updated').removeClass('d-none');
      $(".revnue_updated").fadeOut(3000);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: what's your response type ? @Shivam Singh

Comment: json @AlexJavadi

Comment: why you are using ```.load()```?, I think you need to use ```.append()``` instead. @Shivam Singh